# Layman explanation of "dynamics" or "dynamic behaviour"

Tags: control-system, automotive, terminology, control-theory

I often read the term dynamics or dynamic behaviour in electrical engineering especially in control systems course

What is meant by it?
Is it means that the system whose internal state/properties change with time?please kindly explain with practical example application

Comment: Useful search terms: "step response", "overshoot" "damping" and "stability".

Answer (score 2):

It's just how the system responds to changes in its input, as opposed to the steady-state response, which is how it acts with a constant or periodic input.