# Meaning of "Dynamics" in terms of control systems?

Tags: control, control-system, control-theory

What is meant by "dynamics" in context of control systems?
For example what is difference between the dynamics of an aeroplane and a car?

This question below answers to some extent my question, but not in details (especially in regards to my example above)
[Layman explanation of "dynamics" or "dynamic behaviour"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/465583/layman-explanation-of-dynamics-or-dynamic-behaviour)

Comment: that word is well-defined in dictionaries. Pick a dictionary, and explain why the definition there isn't sufficient – we're not a "looking things up for you" service!

Answer (score 1):

D[efinition of dynamics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dynamics)

1 **physics** : a branch of mechanics that deals with forces and their relation primarily to the motion but sometimes also to the equilibrium of bodies

***Consider a measure of **ratios** of forces, distance, speed, etc*   Therefore consider it opposite to constant**.

2 : a pattern or process of change, growth, or activity population dynamics

3 : variation and contrast in force or intensity (as in music)

*Modern radio music is compressed so the dynamics are lost and the envelope is flat so as not to over-modulate the RF and get maximum amplitude. The AC sound pressure is almost constant, yet the signal to noise ratio is high. Others might say it is all *Noise* ;)*

Answer (score 0):

Dynamics of a closed loop system describes how fast the manipulated value reaches the setpoint value, or how fast the system reacts on a disturbance value.

High dynamics means very high responsiveness.

> Forexample what is difference between dynamics of an aeroplane and a
> car

In control theory, means nothing.